# 2017 Macbook air making popping/crackling noise, even when off

Tags: macbook-pro

I bought a refurbished 2017 macbook air in April 2022. Just last night it started making a relatively loud popping/crackling noise that persists even after the laptop is powered off. It does not appear to be coming from the speakers. After it was turned off, the sound gradually decreased in intensity. Today I turned it back on and the sound restarted, though not as loud as last night. Similar to last night, it continued but slowly attenuated after I powered the laptop off again.

My main concern is that this is coming from the battery and represents an imminent battery failure, which I don't want to happen when it's on my lap. Thoughts on causes, possible solutions, and whether or not this presents any danger?

Here's a quick video I recorded just before powering off the laptop last night. The sound is barely audible in the video but is clearly audible in person. https://photos.app.goo.gl/49bqfW2bajuH1HkJ9

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132423), is it the same thing you're encountering?

Comment: Nope, that link seems to describe issues that are concurrent with audio ("The crackling stops when the audio stream stops, after a few second delay..."). My issue happens even when audio is not playing, starts as soon as the laptop is powered on, and persists after the laptop is powered off and closed.

Comment: Could you manage to locate from where the sound is coming from approximately? (Stick your ear around the mac and see where it is the loudest)